# Size of map output partitions?

Tags: hadoop, mapper, reducers

Let's assume that we have 3 mappers (m1, m2 and m3) and 2 reducers (r1 and r2).

Each reducer fetches its input partitions from the generated files by each mapper.

From the job history, I can extract the total input for each reduce task,
but I would like to know the contribution of each mapper to this reducer input ?

For example, the reducer r1 will receive an INPUT_r1 such as:

INPUT_r1 = ( partition fetched from m1 ) + ( partition fetched from m2 ) + ( partition fetched from m3 )

I would like to know the size of those partitions from mappers ?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things need to be considered in order to find the size of the partitions from the mappers.

First, we should understand that, in Hadoop, *partitioners are executed before combiners,* so if you have a combiner in your logic you will need to account for it... if it influences your attempt to find size. This is relevant if you find size another way than the one I suggest here.

Second, the default partitioner `HashPartitioner` assigns approximately the same number of keys to each reducer. The method used is:

```
public int getPartition(K2 key, V2 value, int numReduceTasks) {

     return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks;
}
```

Note that the partitioner only considers the key and ignores the value which can contribute to uneven distribution of data disseminated to reducers.

What I would do to find out the size is set up a counter near your `HashPartitioner` or custom partitioner and account for the key - value pair sizes being gathered by each. Then print this value out for each partitioner. You may need to keep track of where each partition sends its data since the partitioners themselves have no idea who they are sending their data to.

Lots of the research for this question is referenced from [MapReduce Book](http://lintool.github.com/MapReduceAlgorithms/MapReduce-book-final.pdf)